# OpenGL vs DirectX, local vs global?

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, directx, direct3d

I have read multiple articles and posts about pre/post multiplications, column/row major, DirectX vs OpenGL, and I might be more confused than at the beginning.

So, let's say we write those instructions (pseudocode) in OpenGL:

rotate(...) 
translate(...)

From what I understand, OpenGL will do v' = R * T * v, effectively transforming the local coordinates frame of the vector.

But in DirectX, if we do the transformations (pseudocode) in the same order,

rotate(...)
translate(...)

the result will not be the same, right? Since DirectX pre-multiplies, the result will be v' = v * R * T, thus transforming the vector using global coordinates.

So, am I correct when I say that OpenGL being post-multiplication and DirectX being pre-multiplication is like saying that OpenGL moves in local coordinates while DirectX moves in global coordinates?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no `rotate()` or `translate()` method in either OpenGL or DirectX. So what are you referring to? And the old OpenGL matrix stack functions `glRotatef()` etc. do not count.

Comment: This is why I mentioned pseudocode, because I wanted to compare the 2 libraries without having syntax in the way.

Comment: But if neither of both libraries support this kind of syntax, there is no point in using this kind of pseudo code. More specifically, OpenGL does not have any integrated math and DirectX' math library has been extracted to a library on its own.

Comment: Well, for example, with OpenGL, if the current matrix is the identity and you call glRotatef()  and glTranslatef(), it's the equivalent of doing I * R * T, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But as I mentioned, these methods are deprecated and should not be used any more. Especially, if you are beginning to learn. There is no equivalent of this in DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to read [Matrices, Handedness, Pre and Post Multiplication, Row vs Column Major, and Notations](http://www.seanmiddleditch.com/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/).

- OpenGL code is often using a right-handed coordinate system, column-major matrices, column vectors, and post-multiplication.
- Direct3D code is often using a left-handed coordinate system, row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication.

XNA Game Studio's math library (and therefore Monogame, Unity, etc.) use right-handed coordinate system, row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication.

The [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) library uses row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication, but leaves it up to you to choose to use a left-handed or right-handed coordinate system where it matters. This was even true of the older now [deprecated D3DXMath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

In either system, you are still doing the same object coordinate -> world coordinate -> eye coordinate -> clip coordinate transformations.

So with OpenGL GLM you might do:

```
using namespace glm;

mat4 myTranslationMatrix = translate(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

mat4 myRotationMatrix = rotate( 90.f, vec3( 0, 1, 0 ) );

mat4 myScaleMatrix = scale(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);

mat4 myModelMatrix = myTranslationMatrix * myRotationMatrix * myScaleMatrix;
vec4 myTransformedVector = myModelMatrix * myOriginalVector;
```

In DirectXMath you'd do:

```
using namespace DirectX;

XMMATRIX myTranslationMatrix = XMMatrixTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX myRotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationY(XMConvertToRadians(90.f));

XMMATRIX myScaleMatrix = XMMatrixScaling(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)

XMMATRIX myModelMatrix = myScaleMatrix * myRotationMatrix * myTranslationMatrix;
XMVECTOR myTransformedVector = XMVector4Transform( myOriginalVector, myModelMatrix );
```

And you will get the same transformation as a result.

> If you are new to DirectXMath, then you should take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) which hides some of the strict SIMD-friendly alignment requirements with C++ constructors and operators. Because SimpleMath is based on XNA Game Studio C# math design, it assumes right-handed view coordinates but you can easily mix it with 'native' DirectXMath as well to use left-handed view coordinates if desired.

Most of these decisions were arbitrary, but did have sound design reasoning for them. OpenGL's math library was trying to match normal mathematical convention of post-multiplication, which lead to them adopting column-major matrices. In the early days of Direct3D, the team felt that the reversing of the concatenation order was confusing so they flipped all the conventions.

Many years later, the XNA Game Studio team felt that the traditional Direct3D concatenation order was intuitive, but that having 'forward' be negative z was confusing so they switched to right-handed coordinates. Many of the more modern Direct3D samples therefore use right-handed view systems, but you'll still see a mix of both left and right-handed viewing setups for Direct3D samples.So at this point, we really have "OpenGL style", "classic Direct3D style", and "modern Direct3D style".

> Note that these conventions really mattered back when things were done with fixed-function hardware but with programmable shader pipelines what matters is that you are consistent. In fact, the HLSL shader defaults to expecting matrices to be in column-major form so you'll often see DirectXMath matrices transposed as they are copied into constant buffers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as premultiplication in OpenGL.

The reason why you think OpenGL reverses the multiplications is, that it stores the matrices in column-major layout:

```
a c
b d
```

The mathematical rule for multiplying transposed matrices is:

```
A^T * B^T = (B*A)^T
```

So if you want to compute  `v' = v * R * T` (all row-major matrices) you will have to write

```
(v')^T = v * R * T
```

or in your pseudo-code:

```
translate(...) rotate(...) translate(...)
```

**Alternatively** you could store your rotation and translation matrices column-major too.